# highchart drilldown dynamic point name

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, highcharts

```
 events: {
    drilldown: function (e) {
     if (!e.seriesOptions) {
   var Fruitsname= e.point.name;
  //var Fruitsname='Fruits';
   drilldowns = {
 Fruitname:{
      //  'Fruits': {
          name: 'Fruits',
          data: [
          ['Apples', 5],
          ['Oranges', 7],
          ['Bananas', 2]
            ]
          },
       }
    }
  }
```

}

I got click event on drill down using **e.point.name**, but string name under drill down is taking as in double quotation but it required string in single quote .
I tried using alert and console.log but it is showing without quotes,In breakpoints it showing in double quotes.I have commented line 'Fruits' it works as static value.
can any one knows how to bind point name to drill down.
Any suggestion or help will be appreciated
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
drilldowns = {};
drilldowns[Fruitname] = {
      name: 'Fruits',
      data: [
      ['Apples', 5],
      ['Oranges', 7],
      ['Bananas', 2]
        ]
 }
```